# AVMutableMetadataItem's time & duration INVALID after reading

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I have a question. 
Recently I needed to add custom tags for recorded video. Local video on device not a streamed video. The task is to add some event specific tags in video, position of which could be set by pressing forward/backward like buttons like in any player.

It is not important whether the movie file will be mov file or mp4 format. 
I searched on forum, found several samples how to add metadata using AVExportSession & it worked. 
Although, when I tried to add metadata using `AVAssetWriter`. I wasn't able to append attributes to video.

What I do not understand is that after adding attribute, returned (time & duration) properties are always invalid.

For instance let's say I have a video with duration 2 seconds. 
I have tried different key spaces. I am not able to write keys' from ID3 space.

IS ID3 used for stream video? (as far as I understood ID3 metadata of .mp3). Therefore, I was not able to write it into MPEG-4 file

I also used `QuickTimeUserData` & `ISOUserData` but again results are the same.
Here is an example

```
AVMutableMetadataItem *item2 = [AVMutableMetadataItem new];
item2.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes;
item2.key = AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyUserComment;
item2.value = @"One two three";
item2.duration =CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(1, 1);
item2.time = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0, 1);
```

After reading I got the following:

```
AVMutableMetadataItem: 0xa4301f0, keySpace=itsk, key=\U00a9cmt, commonKey=(null), locale=  (null), value=One two three, time={INVALID}, duration={INVALID}, extras={\n    dataType = 1;\n}
```

I would like to use time & duration properties for metadata instead of writing custom data and processing it after that.

Ideally it would be great to append array of items with time = t1, duration = d1, .... (tn,dn).

Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended with a solution adding chapters to a video file instead of using metadata.

I looked at available libraries, took `mpv4lib`.

The library currently is not compiled for iOS, therefore, I ported the source project into static library for iOS platform.

That library allows to add custom "atoms" to mp4 file, and one of them is Quick Time text track, containing chapters.
I do similar with that [post](http://uzzikie.livejournal.com/17048.html)

The library is located [here](https://code.google.com/p/mp4v2/).